# I have a css problem! When I click on the html screen, it just jumps, two times which isn't expected

Tags: javascript, html, css

My problem is that my css and javascript doesn't really work for my web game jumping, my web game is about Dino game recreation, the one that you play when you have no internet.
Here are the codes:

I watched a tutorial on youtube on how to make a Dino game in html, css, js.
And I came up with this problem on 5:00 - 5:22 in the youtube video, the youtube video link is here https://youtu.be/bG2BmmYr9NQ?si=HsQRuD63MDb70xvs

I've expected it to work just like in the video, but nah, it just resulted in double jumps.
Someone tell me the problem

```js
var character = document.getElementById("character");
var block = document.getElementById("block");

function jump() {
  if (character.classList != "animate") {
    character.classList.add("animate");
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    character.classList.remove("animate");
  }, 500);
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#game {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#character {
  width: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 150px;
}

.animate {
  animation: jump 500ms;
}

#block {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  top: 130px;
  left: 480px;
  animation: block 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes jump {
  0% {
    top: 100px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 150px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 100px;
  }
}

@keyframes block {
  0% {
    left: 480px;
  }
  100% {
    left: -40px
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" onclick="jump()">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Dino Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="game">
    <div id="character"></div>
    <div id="block"> </div>
  </div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess the `remove` does trigger the `animation` again. Because `animation` is like: animate whenever it changes... 

Comment: @deEr. So I commented the code, it is needed to make it jump multiple times, if I remove it it just jumps 1 time only. And no, it didn't fix the double jump problem

Comment: Offtopic: `.classList != "animate"` is a **terrible** way to check for a class.  It might be "ok" in this controlled scenario, or might be addressed later in the video.   `classList` is a *list* so should not be compared with a *string*.  You should be using `!==` which would then break.   Use `!character.classList.contains("animate")`

Comment: If you take out the classList check and the remove, so it's just `.add("animate")`, then you still get the double-jump (though only one of them) - this *confirms* it's not a js problem and an issue in the css.

Comment: @freedomn-m CSS problem is what the OP named the question.  I will have a JSFiddle and try.

Comment: @deEr. lulz - the title was tl;dr     The video segment from 5:00 is entirely about adding js - so the problem would be long before that in the video

Comment: I guess @freedomn-m got here something. When one changes `animation` to `2s` it jumps only once https://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/cmrykqx5/6/ . This next is a bit of a **hack** but it jumps once: https://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/cmrykqx5/9/ .

Comment: @deEr. I did something similar at first, but if you watch in your fiddle, when you jump it very much skips (to use a different term than jump) to the top then slides down - there's no slide up which there should be given the animation.

Comment: I got it. I reversed the `animation` as @freedomn-m said: https://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/cmrykqx5/14/ .

Comment: To cover "*I guess the remove does trigger the animation again*" - the `animation` css attribute can only apply to the element that has the class.  When the class is removed, no animation is applied.    This does cause problems when (eg) a dev wants to fade-in and then fade-out as they put the animate on "show" and add the class (animates) but then doesn't animate when they remove the class - in these cases the animate goes on the parent (not the case in this question to be clear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the character animate `jump` positions are upside-down.

So it skips to the top then slides down then slides back up then when you remove the class it skips to the bottom, thus looking like it jumps twice.

Remember that the `top` value is from the top of the container, not the top of your character. So starts at 150 moves "up" to 100 then back down to 150.

In the video, this is initially (partially IMO) explained @1:50 and the animate values added @2:49

> because the box is 200px and the character is 50px so we need to put it down 150px

```js
var character = document.getElementById("character");
var block = document.getElementById("block");

function jump() {
  if (character.classList != "animate") {
    character.classList.add("animate");
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    character.classList.remove("animate");
  }, 500);
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#game {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#character {
  width: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 150px;
}

.animate {
  animation: jump 500ms;
}

#block {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  top: 130px;
  left: 480px;
  animation: block 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes jump {
  0% {
    top: 150px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 100px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 150px;
  }
}

@keyframes block {
  0% {
    left: 480px;
  }
  100% {
    left: -40px
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" onclick="jump()">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Dino Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="game">
    <div id="character"></div>
    <div id="block"> </div>
  </div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks! didn't expect you to watch the video lol!

Comment: I put it on x2 speed .  It was useful to see what the source had for the css and compare with yours.